Template argument deduction/substitution failed when calling
Either there is something wrong with my C++ understanding, or there's a hidden typo somewhere... I wasted hours on those few LOCs.
First, I defined a start() method as such:
template <typename FunctionResult, typename ...FunctionArgs>
inline std::shared_ptr<StoppableThread> start(
        std::function<FunctionResult(const bool&, FunctionArgs...)> function, FunctionArgs... args)
{ ... }

And also, some threadedSearch() lambda function:
std::function<void(const bool&,
        const Source&, Population&,
        const std::vector<Parameter>&,
        const size_t&, const size_t&)> threadedSearch = ... ;

But when I attempt to perform this:
Source source = { ... };
Population population = { ... };
const std::vector<Parameter> variationsParameters = { ... };
const size_t randomCandidatesCount = ..., lineageCount = ...;

auto searchThread = start(
    threadedSearch,
    source, population,
    variationsParameters,
    randomCandidatesCount, lineageCount);

The compiler disagrees with the latter call to starŧ(), and tells me:
# with g++
error: no matching function for call to
‘start(std::function<void(const bool&, const Source&, Population&, const std::vector<Parameter>&, const long unsigned int&, const long unsigned int&)>&,
Source&, Population&, const std::vector<Parameter>&, const size_t&, const size_t&)’
[...]
note: candidate: ‘template<class FunctionResult, class ... FunctionArgs> std::shared_ptr<StoppableThread>
start(std::function<FunctionResult(const bool&, FunctionArgs ...)>, FunctionArgs ...)
note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note: inconsistent parameter pack deduction with ‘const Source&’ and ‘Source’

# with clang++
error: no matching member function for call to 'start'
note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'FunctionArgs'
(<const Source&, Population&, const std::vector<Parameter>&, const unsigned long&, const unsigned long&>
vs.
<Source, Population, std::vector<Parameter>, size_t, size_t>)

My question is: WTF?
Also: what could I do? Explicitely specifying template parameters in the start<...>() call didn't even work...
I don't know how to make the compiler understand what it should see as the "real" parameters types...
A fully crashing minimal example can be found here: https://onlinegdb.com/FtBIGmkH-

Please show a [mre]

Isn't this one?

No, we don't get that error if we try to compile it.

Oh ok, that's interesting... I'll have a look into it. Thank you two for pointing it out!

Where is the const bool& parameter in your call to start ?

@Issylin : start() doesn't get a const bool& parameter... only the lambda function takes one (i know this is confusing)

Isn't this one?  Copy-and-paste this code into a foo.cpp file.  Compile it.  It fails to compile.  Sad panda.  If we "fill in the blanks" and if the bug is in the blanks not provided, we may not re-invent the bug.

@Eljay : Done. Sorry it took me some time : https://onlinegdb.com/FtBIGmkH-

n.m.'s answer below is complete.  As a quick fix, I got your code to work by doing explicit template parameters auto searchThread = start<void, Source const&, Population&, std::vector<Parameter> const&, size_t const&, size_t const&>(/*...*/.

Please don't edit solutions into the question. A [mre] should be within the question and not rely on external links

whatever_t start(std::function<FunctionResult(const bool&, FunctionArgs...)> function, 
          FunctionArgs... args) 

This has two occirrences of FunctionArgs.... When a part of std::function type, the context is non-deducible, and the pack will be taken from the std::function as is. In the other occurerence the context is deducible, so the pack will be deduced from the actual function argument.
The two packs should be exactly the same in both cases. However FunctionArgs... args will never deduce a reference type, and your function accepts const references. So one pack will be full of const reference types and the other full of non-reference types. This is a substitution failure.
One way to fix the problem is to make the other occurrence non-deducible too.
whatever_t start(std::function<FunctionResult(const bool&, FunctionArgs...)> function, 
      std::type_identity_t<FunctionArgs>... args)

will do the job (requires C++20, but an equivalent of std::type_identity_t can be implemented in a pinch).
Another way is to decouple the function type from the arguments.
template<typename Func, typename ... Args>
whatever_t start(Func&& func, Args&& ... args) 

(to make sure func can be called with args you can use a requires clause or good old SFINAE—or just call it, and deal with less helpful error messages if the call cannot be made),
